# Change surface color in Matplotlib based on a variable

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, simulation, colormap

I have plotted a simple function as a 3D-plot using Matplotlib. Now, I want to create a colormap to color it depending on the speed as derived in the `u` and `v` functions. For that purpose, I want to use the function seen in `c`. How should I go about doing this? Thank you in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 20)
y = np.linspace(-2, 2, 20)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
h = np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2)            # plotted function
u = -2*X*np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2)       # speed in x-direction
v = -2*Y*np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2)       # speed in y-direction
c = np.sqrt(u**2 + v**2)            # colormap derives from this

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8, 7), facecolor='white')
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, h)

plt.show()
```

Comment: pls see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63697379/5855131).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
from matplotlib import cm

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8, 7), facecolor='white')
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, h, rstride=1, cstride=1, facecolors = cm.jet(c/np.amax(c)),
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

plt.show()
```

[image]